# Custom layout of facebook share feeds

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sharer

I know that developers can customize the title, text and provide images on Facebook. However, I cannot figure out how to customize layout with text and images like the following example.

Example image URL: http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=a22bab5

The snapshot is what I saw that Strava shares the information of user activity on Facebook. The facebook feed is not "USERNAME share a link", but "USERNAME ran 14.7 kilometers with Strava." Moreover, the layout of sharing information is also customized, not just a title and paragraphs. The image itself is also larger.

I had referred Facebook Feed and Share Dialogs document, but it only provides the basic sharing example. (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)

Can somebody show me some code examples to achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/overview/

Comment: Add "facebook-opengraph" label.